# Grant or Deny Access to the Reporting Services "Report Manager" Web site

Tags: iis, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

In SSRS2005, we could disable or enable the access to SSRS report by grant the access or deny to IIS IPSecurity.
We have  migrated to SSRS2012 and I couldn't found the SSRS folder in IIS.
Could anyone help me?

Below is the code we use :

```
Set SecObj = GetObject("IIS://LocalHost/W3SVC/1/Root/Reports")
If Not SecObj is nothing Then
    ' Get the IIsIPSecurity object.
    Set MyIPSec = SecObj.IPSecurity
    ' Set GrantByDefault = True/False to grant or deny access to the Web Site.
    If sAction = "GRANT" Then
        MyIPSec.GrantByDefault = True
    Else
        MyIPSec.GrantByDefault = False
    End If      

    ' Set the new security back in the metabase.
    SecObj.IPSecurity = MyIPSec
    SecObj.Setinfo
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to find SSRS in IIS because since SSRS2008, the Report Manager is not hosted in IIS any more, but in [HTTP.sys](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/introduction-to-iis/introduction-to-iis-architecture#Hypertext).

Here is an interesting blog post about it: [Everybody (Why Leave IIS?)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bwelcker/archive/2007/12/04/everybody-why-leave-iis.aspx)

> If you have gotten a chance to try an early build of SQL Server
>   Reporting 2008 Reporting Services, you know that one of the changes in
>   the product is the removal of the Internet Information Services (IIS)
>   dependency.

You will have to find another way to do this.